# print specified amount of lines in file until hitting the end

Tags: linux, bash, sed, split

A brief description of the problem I face, for which I could not find a fitting solution:

I have a file of 8000 log rules and I need to print 100 lines each time, and netcat this to a destination. After hitting the end of the file, I want it to loop back to the beginning of the file and start the process again until I manually stop the looping through the file. This is to test our environment for events per second over a period of time.

I've seen some examples in 'sed' to print a certain amount of lines from a file, but not how it continues on to the next 100 lines and the next 100 lines after that (and so on).

Anyone has a fitting solution? It must be way easier than I'm thinking.

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and sample of expected output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: You could just keep a counter (`counter=1`) and use `tail -n +${counter} | head -n -100` while redirecting your output to `netcat` and then `counter=$((counter + 100))` and do that until `tail` fails. wrap that all in a continual loop `while : ; do ... done` and you should be golden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print every 100 lines of a file you could use `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# line increment
inc=100

# total number of lines in the file
total=$(wc -l < input_file)

for ((i=1;i<total;i=i+inc)); do
   sed -n "$i,$((i+inc-1))p" input_file
done
```

As mentioned in a comment you could redirect the output to netcat, e.g. `{ for ((i=1;i<total;i=i+inc)); do ... done } > netcat [-options]`. Then wrap all that in a continual loop to repeat.

An alternatively is to use `split`.

```
inc=100
split --filter "netcat [options]" -l$inc input_file
```

Comment: That works, you could brace-enclose the `for` loop and redirect the output to `netcat`, e.g. `{ for ((i=1;i<total;i=i+inc)); do ... done } > netcat [-options]`. Then wrap all that in a continual loop to repeat.

Comment: Thankyou for your help!

When I run the script with the provided file (ha.txt) it gives me the following error: 

./ha.sh: line 9: ((: 101 ha.txt: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".txt")

Comment: Double-quote the `sed` command, e.g. `sed -n "$i,$((i+inc-1))p" input_file`

Comment: Also IMHO `total=$(wc -l input_file | awk {'print $1'})` could be changed to `total=$(wc -l < file)` too.

Comment: Hi, David. This still gives me the same output: ./ha.sh: line 9: ((: 101 ha.txt: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".txt"). Any explanation on what the error actually says and why it is thrown?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin and RavinderSigh13 I included your suggestions to improve the script

Comment: Sorry, it seems like my copy pasting keyboard didn't function as well as I wanted it. Apparently I missed the 'awk' part of the answer. It works now, Thanks all!

Comment: @chr0nk, So it means 1 run of script will print 100 sets of lines till end of file right and if you want to re-run it then we need to run the script again correct?

Comment: How are you calling your script and what have you included in it. You must incorporate the commands. You can replace `input _file` with `"$1"` and pass the file to split as the first command line parameter, or do `fname="${1:-input_file}"` to provide a default name and then use `"$fname"` as the file to read.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Well, I wanted it to be a loop. So until I manually stop the printing of the lines, it should be looping through the file 100 lines at a time. Any Idea on how that can be done?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The file is +x'd and is being run. Calling the filename works now, but we missed the awk part and that's what threw the error. Again, thank you for you help.

Comment: @chr0nk, yes that's what I thought and meant in my previous comment, could you please update your question with complete details, lemme write something on same too but please update your post with full details so that people are NOT in confusions as they put efforts to help, please do so.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I thought that telling that 'I want it to start over again' was sufficient, but I will edit it to be more descriptive.

Comment: Just put `while : ; do ....... done` around the whole thing to repeatedly loop and start over at the beginning.